# React Native textInput max length

Tags: react-native

How do you set such attribute? For example the CCV field of credit card should have a max length of 3. Expiry date should have a max length of 2 for month and 4 for years.

Comment: I think you need to do it manually by doing something like `<TextInput maxLength='3' onChange={this.handleMaxLength}>`

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281216/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-length-of-a-textinput-in-react-native?rq=1

Comment: Just a note, a CVV for a credit card could have 4 digits, in some cards.

Answer (score 148):

The `maxLength` prop is now part of React Native:

```
<TextInput value={this.state.text} maxLength={4} />
```

Comment: I have add maxLength={4}  as the props of TextInput, but the simulator allows the input with length more than 4. Is this the limitation of simulator or I miss something?

Comment: @吳強福 That's strange. It works fine for me. And you're on the latest version? (Though this was added well over a year ago...)

Comment: Is there any solution for 'Text' field? because 'maxLength' is not working for 'Text' field.

Comment: maxLength' did not worked for 'TextInput' I had to add  multiline={false} as well. Without adding this maxLength={4} did not worked

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you are using `maxLength` with camel case and not `maxlengh`

it seems obvious but it wasn't to me when i was breaking my head trying to figure it out hope this helps