# Is there a way to limit the length of a TextInput in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to make it so that my program does not allow you to input more than a certain amount of characters into a TextInput component, similar to how maxLength works for input. I haven't been able to find anything similar maxLength for textInput. Is there an easy way to set a maximum number of characters for the < TextInput /> component?

Answer (score 8):

In the props for TextInput you can set a maxLength attribute.

From the documentation:

**maxLength** number

Limits the maximum number of characters that can be entered. Use this instead of implementing the logic in JS to avoid flicker. @platform ios

Comment: maxlength not working in web npm run web,in android and ios working fine,if am placed maxlength=3 and secureTextEntry={true} then working for data is masked

Answer (score 5):

```
<TextInput value={this.state} maxLength={10} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this functionality as well. The example app in react-native called UI Explorer has implemented TextInput with a maxLength property. However, I  believe they made this change on July 22nd for v0.9.0rc. Here are the links -

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commits/master/Examples/UIExplorer/TextInputExample.js

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/961c1eb42904a4d5516fd7939ba14bc0625309d3

The first link is the history of commits for the TextInput example and  the second is the actual commit that concerns you. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: I need to show maximum 15 letters and continue with .. in text component. Is there is any way to acheive ths